# ran npm install on github but cant import the javascript files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I successfully ran npm install on a project named 'react-slingshot-Boilerplate' from github.  In the node_modules folder, I can see the project 'react-slingshot-Boilerplate' after running npm install. I can also find the component I want to import within that node_modules package.

Here is the component I am trying to import the npm installed component INTO:

```
import {LoginPage} from 'react-slingshot-Boilerplate';

class login2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-container">
                <LoginPage></LoginPage>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the component I am trying to import:

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
             constructor(props) {
                 super(props);
             }

    render() {
            return (
                <div >
                    <h1 >hello world</h1>
               </div>
     );
  }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

Comment: Can't find any Github project / npm module with this name `react-slingshot-Boilerplate`. Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the import name. You kept same name for class and import package see this:

//LoginPage is repeated as a class name and import name.

```
import {LoginPage} from 'react-slingshot-Boilerplate';

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
```

Note: `npm install` will install all the libraries which are registered to the npm, saving file directly to the node_module folder and running `npm install` will not work.

Comment: then you are exporting wrong component export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage); and in place of LoginPage it should be login2

Comment: mega apologies.  I royally messed up my question.  I tried to fix it above.  I totally understand if you lost patients with me.  :(

Comment: it's ok i understand :)

Comment: In the second component what are you trying to import?

Comment: can you give me a link of react-native-slingshot or you had created your own npm library?

Comment: I am trying to import the component 'LoginPage' INTO the component login2.  The component 'LoginPage' resides in the node_modules folder 'react-slingshot-Boilerplate'.  I cannot share a link of the project 'react-slingshot-Boilerplate' because it is not registered with NPM.  I installed it from my local github directly.

Comment: oh it's a library in your domain

Comment: I was told that you can use NPM to install a project straight out of github.  That is exactly what I did.  I did not manually copy the project to node_modules.   The command I used was this:  npm install git+https://mygithub/React-Redux-Routing-Boilerplate